# Laravel Eloquent Joining Strange query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using laravel's eloquent in order to query multiple tables in a database. The following query is working. However, I want to add something to the query that will filter out the `milestones` depending on whether the value of `Job` table column `archived` is set to `0` or `1`.

```
$app->get('/dashboard/user', function() {
    global $app;

    $milestones = Milestone::where('user_id', '=', $app->user->user_id)
        ->where('completed_flag', '=', '0')
        ->with('job.businessUnit')
        ->with('user')
        ->orderBy('deadline', 'asc')
        ->get();

    $milestones = $milestones->sort(function($a, $b) {
        $a0 = ($a->milestone_id == $a->job->next_incomplete_milestone_id);
        $b0 = ($b->milestone_id == $b->job->next_incomplete_milestone_id);
        return ( ($a0 == $b0) ? strcmp($a->deadline, $b->deadline) :
                (($a0 == true) ? -1 : 1));
    });
    print json_encode(array(
        'user' => $app->user->toArray(),
        'milestones' => $milestones->toArray()
    ));
});
```

I've been trying to do something along the lines of each of the following:

```
    ->join('jobs','jobs.archived','=','0')
//
    ->where('archived','=','0')
//  
    ->with('jobs.archived')
//
    ->with('jobs')
//
    ->where('jobs.archived', '=', '0')
```

Comment: if you are going to filter this part, `->with('job.businessUnit')`. you could use [eagerLoad constraint](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) method.

For example:

```
$milestones = Milestone::whereHas('job', function($query) {
    $query->where('archived','=','0');
})
... // took out rest of code for brevity
->get();
```

This `whereHas` example will only retrieve Milestone with a Job that has the archived value of 0.

Regarding the comment above mentioned by @Tezla, I don't think constraining eager loads is what you want because it will still get you Milestone that don't match the requirement. Rather, it will simply return an empty Job collection for the relationship.

Comment: Hmmm, this starts the query in a different place, so it's not really doing the same thing, since I'm having the most difficulty using two tables Milestone and Job and then using the Job column `archived`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to do something that would mirror the following `SQL` query

```
SELECT * FROM milestones JOIN jobs ON milestones.job_id = jobs.job_id WHERE milestones.user_id = 2 AND milestones.completed_flag = 0 AND jobs.archived = 0;
```

Which has an `INNER JOIN` on jobs and milestones.

```
$app->get('/dashboard/user', function() {
    global $app;

    $milestones = Milestone::where('user_id', '=', $app->user->user_id)
        ->join('jobs', 'jobs.job_id', '=', 'milestones.job_id')
        ->where('jobs.archived', '=', '0')

        ->where('completed_flag', '=', '0')
        ->with('job.businessUnit')
        ->with('user')
        ->orderBy('deadline', 'asc')
        ->get();
    $milestones = $milestones->sort(function($a, $b) {
        $a0 = ($a->milestone_id == $a->job->next_incomplete_milestone_id);
        $b0 = ($b->milestone_id == $b->job->next_incomplete_milestone_id);
        return ( ($a0 == $b0) ? strcmp($a->deadline, $b->deadline) :
                (($a0 == true) ? -1 : 1));
    });
    $milestones = $milestones->values();
    print json_encode(array(
        'user' => $app->user->toArray(),
        'milestones' => $milestones->toArray()
    ));
});
```